# Is there a tutorial on how to create Umbraco v4 backoffice extensions

Tags: .net, content-management-system, umbraco

Since the recent announcement that umbraco 5 is discontinued, I have to be work with umbraco 4.7. I need to extend and/or add functionality to the umbraco backoffice. Does anyone know a good tutorial or a forum post on the subject.

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: What are you trying to extend exactly? Are you looking to add another section, like the content, media or settings sections? Or are you looking for information on how to create a package?

Comment: That too, but my imediate task is to contribute to the search functionality. (For example to be able to search for a particular image that was uploaded.). I was wondering how can I register an extension to that bit, if possible at all. I guess my question is more general, how does one go about building an extension to the backoffice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extending the umbraco dashboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967464/extending-the-umbraco-dashboard)

Answer (score 2):

This article will get you along way towards what you want:

http://www.geckonewmedia.com/blog/2009/8/3/how-to-create-a-custom-section-in-umbraco-4

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to extend Umbraco's functionality is to subscribe to Umbraco [events](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/api-cheatsheet/using-applicationbase-to-register-events/overview-of-all-events). The Umbraco [wiki](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/api-cheatsheet/using-applicationbase-to-register-events) gives a simple example of how to this. I don't see any specific event for searching. That seems more like a core feature. If you want to get involved with the Umbraco project, you can fork the source and make a pull request with your edits on [CodePlex](http://umbraco.codeplex.com/).